# take n elements from the front of the list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am a beginner in Prolog and I am trying to write the predicates which hold true when taking n elements from the front of the list. This is what I have written and it doesn't seem to work:
`take(N, List, Front):- length(Front, N), append(Front, [], List).`
I assumed that for take(N, List, Front) to hold true, List and Front must be the same lists which means `append(Front, [], List)` must hold true, and Front must be of size N, therefore `length(Front, N)` must hold true.

Now when I try this in the interpreter, I get the following:

`29 ?- take(5, [1,2,3,4,5], Polo).`
`Polo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
`30 ?- take(3, [1,2,3,4,5], Ok).`
`false.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to take `N` elements from the front of `List`, it's just like taking `N - 1` elements from the front of the tail of `List`, with the head of the `List` tacked on. Unsurprisingly, taking 0 elements from anything is an empty list. (Remember that you can deconstruct a `List` as `[Head | Tail]`.)

EDIT: Why does `take(N, List, Front):- length(Front, N), append(Front, _, List).` work?

Because both `length` and `append` do something very similar to the above. `length(Front, N)` will make `Front` to be `[F1, F2, F3... FN]`, with `N` unknowns. `_` can be anything, so it can be another list with some unknowns. Then `append(Front, _, List)` goes and concatenates the two lists of unknowns, and equates each element of the concatenation to the elements of `List`. For example, if you have `N` as 2, and `List` as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, then `append(Front, _, List)` will make sure that `[F1, F2, U1, U2, U3]` matches `List`:

`append([F1, F2], _, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` asserts that `F1 = 1` and `append([F2], _, [2, 3, 4, 5])`. This asserts that `F2 = 2` and `append([], _, [3, 4, 5])`. This, in turn, is the break condition for `append`, which asserts that `_ = [3, 4, 5]`, which is trivially true. So `Front = [F1, F2] = [1, 2]`.

The way `length` constructs `[F1, F2]` is similar: `length(First, 2)` asserts that `length(FirstTail, 1)`, and this asserts `length(FirstTailTail, 0)`, which is the break condition, so `FirstTailTail = []`, which makes `First = [F1 | [F2 | []]] = [F1, F2]`.

Comment: Thanks that would definitely work, but for some reason If I change take(N, List, Front):- length(Front, N), append(Front, [], List). to take(N, List, Front):- length(Front, N), append(Front, _, List). it works fine. Can someone please explain why.

Comment: I mean this one: take(N, List, Front):- length(Front, N), append(Front, _, List).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes it a lot clearer.